# PageMethod issue with C# and uilang javascript to make placeholder Visible

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, pagemethods

I have a div box that slides into view when one of three buttons are clicked: undergrad, masters and certificates. This animation is done with uilang code (for those that don't know what uilang is you can go to uilang.com). When the button is clicked We want a list to dynamically display into the div. The list will be undergrad degrees, masters or certificates.

So the uilang slide animation is working fine. I created a separate button to test if the asp placeholder is working and it is. The list displays fine so I know there is nothing wrong with the sql or anything like that.

Here is code

// index top of page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="online_programs" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

// form and code on index page

```
<form id="myform" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
        
        <script>
                    
            function ugradList() {
                PageMethods.underGradList();
            }
        
            function mList() {
                PageMethods.masterList();
            }
            
            function cList() {
                PageMethods.certificateList();
            }
        
        </script>

        <label id="underGradButton" onclick="ugradList()" class="toggle-btn"><input type="radio" name="group3" /><i class="fa fa-circle darkgreen">&nbsp;</i>&nbsp;Undergraduate</label>
                     

                    
                    
        <label id="masterButton" onclick="mList()" class="toggle-btn"><input type="radio" name="group3"/><i class="fa fa-circle darkgreen">&nbsp;</i>&nbsp;Graduate </label>
                     
                     
                     
        <label id="certificateButton" onclick="cList()" class="toggle-btn"><input type="radio" name="group3"/><i class="fa fa-circle darkgreen">&nbsp;</i>&nbsp;Certificate </label>


         <asp:Label ID="PrevParentIDLabel" runat="server" Text="0" />
                    
                    <div id="degree-list">

                    
                   
                    
                    <ul><asp:PlaceHolder ID="BachelorsPlaceHolder" runat="server" Visible="false" /></ul>
                   
                    <ul><asp:PlaceHolder ID="MastersPlaceHolder" runat="server" Visible="false" /></ul>
              
                    
                    <ul><asp:PlaceHolder ID="CertificatePlaceHolder" runat="server" Visible="false" /></ul>
                    
                    
                    
                    </div>


        </ContentTemplate>
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
```

// uilang code

```
<code>

 
   clicking on ".toggle-btn" adds class "show-degree-results" on "#degree-results"

   clicking on ".close-results" removes class "show-degree-results" on "#degree-results"
 
   

</code>
```

The problem I have is that when the buttons are clicked it does not display the list! I get the following logs when I inspect:

> The server method 'underGradList' failed with the following error: System.NullReferenceException-- Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> The server method 'masterList' failed with the following error: System.NullReferenceException-- Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> The server method 'certificateList' failed with the following error: System.NullReferenceException-- Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Like I said before I created a test button and pulled out one of the placeholders to test and make sure my other code is working. It worked fine. So I know I do not need help with that, but I am doing something wrong or I am missing something and I am jsut not sure what it is. Below is the C#:

```
public partial class online_programs : System.Web.UI.Page
{

     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {  
        // Our sql and other code that is working fine
     }

     // bachelor function
     [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
     public static void underGradList()
     {                          
                                
       online_programs currentclass = new online_programs();

    
    
    
    
       currentclass.MastersPlaceHolder.Visible = false;
    
    
    
       currentclass.CertificatePlaceHolder.Visible = false;
    
    
    
       currentclass.BachelorsPlaceHolder.Visible = true;
    
    
    
    

    
    

    
     }




    // Master function
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void masterList()
    {                           

        online_programs currentclass = new online_programs();
    
        currentclass.BachelorsPlaceHolder.Visible = false;
        currentclass.CertificatePlaceHolder.Visible = false;
        currentclass.MastersPlaceHolder.Visible = true;
        
    
    
    
     }




     // Certificate function
     [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
     public static void certificateList()
     {

    
        online_programs currentclass = new online_programs();

        currentclass.BachelorsPlaceHolder.Visible = false;
        currentclass.MastersPlaceHolder.Visible = false;
        currentclass.CertificatePlaceHolder.Visible = true;
        
    
    
     }

}
```

I am very new to C# so if there is something missing or if you need more information please just ask. Like I said the other code is working fine. What I have provided is where the issue is. Please help!

Comment: If you want to hide particular element , then why you need a webmethod unless you need any server code operation, you can directly show/hide them in javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I agree with Arindam. But also, if you do need server side interaction, you should consider that WebMethod and PageMethod are deprecated. You should use [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) instead.

Comment: I'm possibly going to fall back to javascript, but this way was really going to make things easier on us. We were piggy backing on code from another page and we were going to use this for something else later on.